# Why TE0 mode does not exist in parallel plates?

Tags: electromagnetism, waveguide

In parallel plates, TM0 mode will become TEM0 mode, but why TE0 mode does not exist? How to explain it with its physical properties?

Comment: Are the plates PEC (perfect electric conductor)?

Comment: Yes.They are PEC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field of the TE$_m$ mode in parallel plate waveguides, derived from Maxwell's equations is:
$$\mathbf E(\mathbf x) = \hat {\mathbf y} E_0 \sin(\frac{m \pi}{d}x) \ e^{-i\beta z}$$
(See the figure below). You can easily see that for the TE$_0$ case ($m=0$), we have the trivial answer of $\mathbf E=0$, which is why the TE modes start at TE$_1$. This doesn't happen with the TM$_0$ mode because it behaves like a cosine function instead of sine, meaning that it is nonzero at $m=0$.

Check out [these lecture notes](https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0xKvG9rDYAhXSYlAKHUf7DO0QFgg0MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcourses.cit.cornell.edu%2Fece303%2FLectures%2Flecture25.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1lqVnPHO7YlLmBpQBnUy5e) if you want to see where these equations come from.

[image]

Comment: I had known the mathematical reason,but can you explain it with its physical reason?

Comment: @Franklin, since there can be no electric field inside a PEC (by definition), the tangential component of $\mathbf{E}$ at the surfaces of the plates must be zero ([the tangential component of $\mathbf{E}$ is continuous across a boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields#Interface_conditions_for_electric_field_vectors))  thus the sine function.  Is this the physical reason you're looking for?